# How do I get a range's address including the worksheet name, but not the workbook name, in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

If I have a Range object--for example, let's say it refers to cell `A1` on a worksheet called `Book1`.  So I know that calling `Address()`  will get me a simple local reference: `$A$1`.  I know it can also be called as `Address(External:=True)` to get a reference including the workbook name and worksheet name: `[Book1]Sheet1!$A$1`.

What I want is to get an address including the sheet name, but not the book name.  I really don't want to call `Address(External:=True)` and try to strip out the workbook name myself with string functions.  Is there any call I can make on the range to get `Sheet1!$A$1`?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Only way I can think of is to concatenate the worksheet name with the cell reference, as follows:

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim cellAddress As String
Set cell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
cellAddress = cell.Parent.Name & "!" & cell.Address(External:=False)
```

EDIT:

Modify last line to :

```
cellAddress = "'" & cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & cell.Address(External:=False)
```

if you want it to work even if there are spaces or other funny characters in the sheet name.

Comment: Well, that works for what I need to do.  Thanks.  I would modify the last line to:

    cellAddress = "'" & cell.Parent.Name & "'!" & cell.Address(External:=False)

so that it works even if there are spaces or other funny characters in the sheet name.

Answer (score 19):

```
Split(cell.address(External:=True), "]")(1)
```

Comment: Nice and concise option. +1

Comment: Yeah, I like this conceptually but it won't work as is when the sheet name has spaces and therefore needs single quotes (ie, 'My Sheet')

Comment: Using this in C# `string address = range.get_Address(true, true, XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, true).Replace(workbook.Name, "").Replace("[]", "");`

Answer (score 3):

Ben is right. I also can't think of any way to do this. I'd suggest either the method Ben recommends, or the following to strip the Workbook name off.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim address As String
Set cell = Worksheets(1).Cells.Range("A1")
address = cell.address(External:=True)
address = Right(address, Len(address) - InStr(1, address, "]"))
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Address()` worksheet function does exactly that. As it's not available through `Application.WorksheetFunction`, I came up with a solution using the `Evaluate()` method.

This solution let Excel deals with spaces and other funny characters in the sheet name, which is a nice advantage over the previous answers.

Example:

```
Evaluate("ADDRESS(" & rng.Row & "," & rng.Column & ",1,1,""" & _
    rng.Worksheet.Name & """)")
```

returns exactly "Sheet1!$A$1", with a `Range` object named `rng` referring the A1 cell in the Sheet1 worksheet.

This solution returns only the address of the first cell of a range, not the address of the whole range ("Sheet1!$A$1" vs "Sheet1!$A$1:$B$2"). So I use it in a custom function:

```
Public Function AddressEx(rng As Range) As String

    Dim strTmp As String

    strTmp = Evaluate("ADDRESS(" & rng.Row & "," & _
        rng.Column & ",1,1,""" & rng.Worksheet.Name & """)")

    If (rng.Count > 1) Then

        strTmp = strTmp & ":" & rng.Cells(rng.Count) _
            .Address(RowAbsolute:=True, ColumnAbsolute:=True)

    End If

    AddressEx = strTmp

End Function
```

The full documentation of the Address() worksheet function is available on the Office website: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ADDRESS-function-D0C26C0D-3991-446B-8DE4-AB46431D4F89

Comment: Care needs to be taken as the argument to `Evaluate()` must be less than 255 characters. Maybe the limit is higher, but there is definately a limit. With really long sheet names this could fail unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following worked for me in a user defined function I created. I concatenated the cell range reference and worksheet name as a string and then used in an Evaluate statement (I was using Evaluate on Sumproduct).

For example:

```
Function SumRange(RangeName as range)   

Dim strCellRef, strSheetName, strRngName As String

strCellRef = RangeName.Address                 
strSheetName = RangeName.Worksheet.Name & "!" 
strRngName = strSheetName & strCellRef
```

Then refer to strRngName in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write code that handles a range with multiple areas, which this does:

```
Public Function GetAddressWithSheetname(Range As Range, Optional blnBuildAddressForNamedRangeValue As Boolean = False) As String

    Const Seperator As String = ","

    Dim WorksheetName As String
    Dim TheAddress As String
    Dim Areas As Areas
    Dim Area As Range

    WorksheetName = "'" & Range.Worksheet.Name & "'"

    For Each Area In Range.Areas
'           ='Sheet 1'!$H$8:$H$15,'Sheet 1'!$C$12:$J$12
        TheAddress = TheAddress & WorksheetName & "!" & Area.Address(External:=False) & Seperator

    Next Area

    GetAddressWithSheetname = Left(TheAddress, Len(TheAddress) - Len(Seperator))

    If blnBuildAddressForNamedRangeValue Then
        GetAddressWithSheetname = "=" & GetAddressWithSheetname
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rngYourRange.Address(,,,TRUE)
```

Shows External Address, Full Address

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he/she does not want to use `.Address` yet you are proposing to use it. Is there any reason to that? Otherwise, I'd suggest that you delete or edit your reply.

Comment: @ArnonK that is not the question because in this case you have workbook in response

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found to do this is to use the following code:

```
Dim SelectedCell As String

'This message Box allows you to select any cell on any sheet and it will return it in the format of =worksheetname!$A$X" where X is any number.

SelectedCell = Application.InputBox("Select a Cell on ANY sheet in your workbook", "Bookmark", Type:=8).Address(External:=True)

SelectedCell = "=" & "'" & Right(SelectedCell, Len(SelectedCell) - Len("[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]") - 1)

'Be sure to modify Sheet1.Cells(1,1) with the Sheet and cell you want to use as the destination. I'd recommend using the Sheets VBA name.

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = SelectedCell
```

How it works;

By Clicking on the desired cell when the message box appears. The string from "Address(External:=True)" (i.e ['[Code Sheet.xlsb]Settings'!$A$1) is then modified to remove the full name of the worksheet([Code Sheet.xlsb]).

Using the previous example it does this by taking the "Len" of the full length of;

[Code Sheet.xlsb]Settings'!$A$1 and subtracts it with the Len of ([Code Sheet.xlsb] -1). leaving you with Settings'!$A$1.

```
 SelectedCell = "=" & "'" & Right(SelectedCell, Len(SelectedCell) - Len("[" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "]") - 1)
```

The Code then its and "='" to insure that it will be seen as a Formula (='Settings'!$A$1).

Im not sure if it is only on Excel on IOS but for some reason you will get an Error Code if you add the "='" in any other way than "=" & "'" as seen bellow.

```
SelectedCell = "=" & "'" & Right....
```

From here all you need is to make the program in the Sheet and cell you want your new formula in.

```
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = SelectedCell
```

By Opening a new Workbook the full Code above will work as is.

This Code is Especially useful as changing the name of the workbook or the name of the sheet that you are selecting from in the message box will not result in bugs later on.

Thanks Everyone in the Forum before today I was not aware that External=True was a thing, it will make my coding a lot easier. Hope this can also help someone some day.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just return the worksheet name with
**address = cell.Worksheet.Name**
then you can concatenate the address back on like this
**address = cell.Worksheet.Name & "!" & cell.Address**

Comment: I think the Cell.Worksheet.Name is only going to get the ActiveSheet name, which isn't what the OP wanted?  It specifically gets a numbered worksheet...

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Range("A1:E10")
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To rg.Rows.Count

    For j = 1 To rg.Columns.Count
    rg.Cells(i, j).Value = rg.Cells(i, j).Address(False, False)

    Next
Next
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please explain why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

For confused old  me  a range

.Address(False, False, , True)

seems to give in format  TheSheet!B4:K9

If it does not why the criteria .. avoid Str functons

will probably only take less  a millisecond and use 153 already used electrons

about 0.3 Microsec

RaAdd=mid(RaAdd,instr(raadd,"]") +1)

or

'about  1.7 microsec

RaAdd= split(radd,"]")(1)

Answer (score -2):

[edit on 2009-04-21]

*As Micah pointed out, this only works when you have named that
 
    particular range (hence .Name anyone?)  Yeah, oops!*

[/edit]

A little late to the party, I know, but in case anyone else catches this in a google search (as I just did), you could also try the following:

```
Dim cell as Range
Dim address as String
Set cell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
address = cell.Name
```

This should return the full address, something like "=Sheet1!$A$1".

Assuming you don't want the equal sign, you can strip it off with a Replace function:

```
address = Replace(address, "=", "")
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when I tried it.  I got an error when it hit cell.Name.  According to the VBA help, the Name property of a Range object returns a Name object, and is only valid when the object refers to a named range.

Comment: Ack!  You're totally right.  Somehow, I just happened to have named that range when I was testing.  I'll be updating my response accordingly :(