# get_Address() not in correct format

Tags: c#, excel, .net-3.5

I am performing search within excel `workbook` using small c# application. 
now, when match found I am trying to get the full row details and the bounded into `datagridview` as shown below, but my problem is that

```
get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, missing, missing)
```

is not show in correct format within the `select statement`

```
  SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:I24] //correct format 
  SELECT * FROM [sheet$B952]
```

so I am getting error message says

> The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object
>   'sheet$B952'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name
>   and the path name correctly. If 'sheet$B952' is not a local object,
>   check your network connection or contact the server administrator.

I tried to use `get_AddressLocal` or the `xlA1` style but that is wont help me 
to get the correct format

please if anyone can help or provide me with better solution or scenario

Thank alot

```
    private void B_General_Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range firstFind = null;

        string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DefaultDirectory + @"\new29.xlsx" + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TB_Search_Text.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("enter text for search");
            return;
        }

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(DefaultDirectory + @"\new29.xlsx",   //---Filename OR FilePath
                                 0,          //---object UpdateLinks
                                 true,       //---object ReadOnly
                                 missing,    //5//---object Format
                                 "",         //---object Password
                                 "",         //---object WriteResPassword
                                 false,      //---object ReadOnlyRecommend
                                 Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,     //---object Origin
                                 "",         //---object Delimiter
                                 true,       //---object Editable
                                 false,      //---object Notify
                                 0,          //---object Converter
                                 true,       //---object AddToMru
                                 false,      //---object Local
                                 false);     //---object CorruptLoad;

        //loop to search witin all excel sheets (workbook)
        foreach (Excel.Worksheet SheetID in oWB.Worksheets)
        {
            Excel.Range oRng = oXL.get_Range("A1", "XFD1048576");

            currentFind = oRng.Find(TB_Search_Text.Text,
                                    missing,
                                    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues,
                                    Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
                                    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                                    Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
                                    false,
                                    missing,
                                    missing);

            while (currentFind != null)
            {
                //Keep track of the first range you find.
                if (firstFind == null)
                {
                    firstFind = currentFind;
                }
                else if (currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, missing, missing) == firstFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, missing, missing))
                {
                    break;
                }
                //currentFind.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                //currentFind.Font.Bold = true;

                currentFind = oRng.FindNext(currentFind);

                //SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B14:I24] correct format 
                //SELECT * FROM [sheet$B952]   XXXXX
                string cmdtxt = @"select * from [" + SheetID.Name + "$" + currentFind.get_Address(true, true, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlR1C1, missing, missing) + "]";
                MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt);
                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtxt, conn);
                    DA.Fill(dt);
                    DGV_Data.DataSource = dt;
                    conn.Close();
                }                
            }
        }

        oWB.Close(false, missing, missing);

        //oSheet = null;
        oWB = null;
        oXL.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem is the different sheet name: `Sheet1` vs. `sheet`. Both A1 and R1C1 reference types should work, but what you want is not the address of the range (its top left cell), but the range as a whole; related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1266074/1132334

Comment: What's the actual name of your worksheet?  Does it (the name) contain any spaces?

Comment: You don't seem to be scoping the Find() to `SheetID` ?Also, you're not expanding the found range (which is a single cell) to the full row you want to return.

Comment: `oXL.get_Range` - this is using the "ActiveSheet" of the "ActiveWorkbook" making the `foreach ` loop scan the same worksheet on each iteration.

Comment: @dlatikay sheet name is correct `sheet` I checked within excel file and when the message `MessageBox.Show(cmdtxt);` promote is correct and even if changed it will automatically get it 
@TimWilliams please :)

Comment: @TnTinMn umm the code works find the only problem I am facing is that I want to display the full row details if there is a match within the row, so I populated to `datagridview` but it is not getting the correct address for cell 
it shown `SELECT * FROM [sheet$B952]` nested of `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B952:I24]` the `:` is missing