# SUM a range where the range is a variable

Tags: vba, excel, variables, sum

I have:

```
Set QuanityRange = Sheets("Raw_Data").Range("F2:F" & lastDataRow)
MsgBox "This is the Data Range: " & vbNewLine & "Quanities: " & QuanityRange.Address()
```

This displays $F$2:$F$1838 in the message box.

Then if I have:

```
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(QuanityRange)
MsgBox "Total is: " & Total
```

This displays 15170 in the message box.

My problem is that I currently have:

```
Range("B2", Cells(lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol)).Formula = "=Sum(Raw_Data!$F$2:$F$10000)"
```

This works, it puts 15170 in each cell from B2 to BO114 which happens to be the location of (lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol) in this case.

However, what I want to do is:

```
Range("B2", Cells(lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol)).Formula = "=Sum(QuanityRange)"
```

instead of:

```
Range("B2", Cells(lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol)).Formula = "=Sum(Raw_Data!$F$2:$F$10000)"
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Comment: It would really help if you put two screenshots. And hardcode `lastMatrixRow` and `lastMatrixCol` to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with:

Range("B2", Cells(lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol)).Formula = "=Sum(" & QuanityRange.Address() & ")"

Comment: Returns all zeros instead of 15170

Comment: Is `B2` on the `Raw_Data` sheet or another one?

Comment: Let me back up... Really what I am trying to accomplish is to sum from F2 to the last row in column F that has data. I wasn't sure how to accomplish this so I named that range "QuanityRange" but if there is a simpler way... I am all for it...

Comment: no its on another sheet... the sheet is named "Matrix"

Comment: @XCELLGUY so does the above work if you change it to `"=Sum(Matrix!" & QuanityRange.Address() & ")"`

Comment: Range("B2", Cells(lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol)).Formula = "=Sum(Matrix!" & QuanityRange.Address() & ")"

Comment: still all zeros

Comment: Set Start = Sheets("Matrix").Range("B2")

Comment: then changed "B2" to Start... but it still didn't work

Comment: @XCELLGUY if that's all you wanted to do, why not update your formula to be "=Sum(Raw_Data!$F$2:$F$999999)" ?

Comment: I figured it out partial thanks to PGCodeRider... not Matrix!... I needed Raw_Data!

Comment: Range("B2", Cells(lastMatrixRow, lastMatrixCol)).Formula = "=Sum(Raw_Data!" & QuanityRange.Address() & ")"

Comment: @XCELLGUY FWIW, better not to hardcode the sheet name - use `QuanityRange.Parent.Name` - just in case you change the sheet name down the road. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131121/how-do-i-get-a-ranges-address-including-the-worksheet-name-but-not-the-workboo).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the address of a range variable in a formula - this is one solution:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim varRange As Range
    Set varRange = Range("F1:F5")
    Range("A1", Cells(3, 3)).Formula = "=Sum(" & varRange.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

The idea is that the formula to the right should be "translatable" to a string.